FFmpeg is not using some images as frames
I've a series of 400 images here a selection and I want to make a video.
The images are are basically the original images or some transofrmations of that (i.e. desaturated and inverted, or with a red filter and so on).
In my script I have:
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i "$output_folder/${filename}-img-x-video-%03d.jpg" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" "${output_folder}/${filename}-video.mp4"

But somehow in the output video which you can find also here there are some images which are not shown on the video. In the folder I've linked you see images from -044 until -053, well in the video:

image 42 is a desaturated & inverted version of the original image
image 43 is a desaturated & inverted versione of the original image
image 44 is a desaturated & inverted versione of the original image
image 45 is the original image → but in the video it is replaced from the inverted one!
image 46 is a desaturated & inverted versione of the original image
image 47 is the original image → but in the video it is replaced from the inverted one!
image 48 is a desaturated & inverted versione of the original image
image 49 is a red-filtered version of the original image
image 50 is a red-filtered version of the original image
image 51 is a red-filtered version of the original image
image 52 is a desaturated & inverted % white-filtered version of the original image → but in the video it is replaced from the red-filtered one
image 53 is a red-filtered version of the original image
image 54 is a red-filtered version of the original image
image 55 is the original image
image 56 is the original image
image 57 is the original image
image 58 is the original image

So, the strange thing is that sometimes (for example in frame 45, 47, 52) there is not the images they should be. It is like that if there is a single image (i.e. image 45 is the only original image between several inverted images, before and after), this is replaced in the frame by the previous one).
In terminal I become sometimes that warning message:
[swscaler @ 0x55e0e0b6cd80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly

Maybe there is a correlation?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi. I have 400 images and I want to make a video. Each image a frame of that video. The strange thing is that sometimes (for example in frame 45, 47, 52) of that video there is not the images they should be, in the contrary that frames are the same of the previous ones (I.e. 44, 46, 51). I hope it's clearer now...

Do the actual images appear later, after the duplication?

no, they seems to be replaced. t is like that if there is a single image (i.e. image 45 is the only original image between several inverted images, before and after), this is replaced in the frame by the previous one)

The issue is resembled the issue described here, but with JPEG images.
Adding -reinit_filter 0 argument may solve the issue.
We may also remove the filters part -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p". We don't need the framerate conversion (we have -framerate 25). We don't need the format conversion (we have -pix_fmt yuvj420p).
Try the following command:
ffmpeg -reinit_filter 0 -framerate 25 -i "$output_folder/${filename}-img-x-video-%03d.jpg" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p "${output_folder}/${filename}-video.mp4"

Adding -reinit_filter 0 is required, because the images have different pixel format (mix of Y and YUV420 pixel formats).
We may check the pixel format using MediaInfo tool:
One image information is:
Image
Format                                   : JPEG
Width                                    : 4 004 pixels
Height                                   : 4 004 pixels
Color space                              : Y

Other image information is:
Image
Format                                   : JPEG
Width                                    : 4 004 pixels
Height                                   : 4 004 pixels
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0


Note:
There might be other issues - the answer address only the posted sample images.

Thanks. I'll try ASAP!

I become another error:
frame=   40 fps= 11 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55ff802d84c0] Changing frame properties on the fly is not supported by all filters.
[libx264 @ 0x55ff802e0bc0] Input picture width (1000) is greater than stride (0)
Video encoding failed
Conversion failed!
[...]
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55f2637c0100] moov atom not found
/home/ste/cose-vecchie-si-possono-buttare-ma-sono-feticista/bilder/output/NAB4-facsimile-4seitig-confezione-page001-video.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input

See the note at the end of my answer... For checking if my solution is reproducible, please try the following: 1. Download the 10 images you have shared to temporary folder. 2. Execute the following command: ffmpeg -y -reinit_filter 0 -framerate 25 -start_number_range 1000 -i "NAB4-facsimile-4seitig-confezione-page001-img-x-video-%03d.jpg" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p "test.mp4". 3. Check if test.mp4 is the expected output (if not, it's probably FFmpeg version issue).

I think that error message Input picture width (1000) is greater than stride (0) means that there is an invalid JPEG image file (it could be other image format with .jpg extension for example). Please make sure that all the JPEG files are valid. Please make sure that the resolution of all the JPEG files is 4004x4004. Try to find a sequence that reproduces the error, and share the images.

I found a workaround.
Before I let ffmpeg work I convert all images with imagemagick:
mogrify -path /path/to/folder/ -set colorspace sRGB /path/to/folder/*.*

